# return value from function with post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have function:

```
function test(){
   $.post('data.php', function(val){
       return val;
   })

   return 'error';
}
```

and i use this simply:

```
console.log(test());
```

post is doing - return good value, but function test return me 'error' instead of value from data.php.
Is possible get value from $.post? If yes, how?

Comment: @reikyoushin Nope. Will return `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is returning 'error' before the post is finished because post is asynchronous. Try using callbacks. Something like this:

```
function test(callback) {
    $.post('data.php', function(val){
        callback(val);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        callback('error');
    });
}

function log(message) {
    console.log(message);
}

test(log);
```

Answer (score 4):

A `return` statement doesn't bubble up functions to the global scope, and if you look carefully, you can see that `return val` lives inside its own function.

In addition to that, that function isn't executed synchronously, so it will never have a chance to return before it's executed.

Therefore, you need to either pass in a callback or use a promises pattern. Googling these words will find you a wealth of information on both.

Answer (score 0):

Use promises to handle errors. It your code return 'error' will be called before callback in post method.

```
function test(){
   $.post('data.php', function(val){
       alert (val);
   }).fail(function(){ alert('error');});


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
function test(callback){
   $.post('data.php', function(val){
       if(typeof callback == 'function') callback(val);
   })
}
```

And call with

```
test(function(val){ console.log(val) });
```